# CSV to WordPress posts: do I have to populate each possible field?

Tags: import, woocommerce-offtopic, csv

I'm planning to import Products in a CSV to WooCommerce.

We are still working on an Excel, and we are using the main fields that a product has, following the WooCommerce wordings for the Products (post_title, post_excerpt, post_content, sku, regular_price, images).

However, we have no columns for ID for example, or comments_status or post_author.

My thinking goes that those fields would be auto-populated by WordPress with a kind of "default", but, hence my question, I'm not sure.

Do I have to include ALL the fields that a Product (or Post or Page) has, so the import is successful?

If so, is it enough to give an ascening ID to the products? (if the last created ID on the site is 35, assign IDs like so: 36, 37, 38, etc).

Thanks for your inputs,

Comment: SKU is the **Stock Keeping Unit**, this is usually akin to the Product ID.  ID on the other hand is an auto-generated primary key.  You need to look at the import page, which usually has directions, including the field formats, and fields expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, the WP is pretty flexible about this and will perfectly handling omitted fields. Including assigning IDs (which is actually best left to it, outside of edge cases when exact IDs must be imported).

The only situation that natively won't let you create post is if neither of title/content/excerpt is provided and post type supports any of them. Even then there is `wp_insert_post_empty_content` filter available to adjust the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably find your post is flagged as off-topic but if it isn't, I'd strongly suggest using one of the WooCommerce import plugins rather than a manual import.

WooThemes have one on their site specifically for importing CSV. Another very powerful tool is WP All Import (and WooCommerce extension). I've tried the manual path - these tools are a much better route.